# JavaScript add column to table

Tags: jquery

I want to add a single column to my html table. My code is:

```
$('#addColumn').click(function(){
                $('#contentTable').css('width', $('#contentTable').width()+150)
                $("#contentTable tr:first").append("<td style="+"width:150px"+">Col</td>");
                $("#contentTable tr:gt(0)").append("<td style="+"width:150px"+"></td>");
            });
```

This script adds new column as last column in table. How is it possible to add new column as `(n-1)` columns? I mean that if there are `ABC`columns script should add new column `D` for `ABDC`.

@UPDATE
before

[image]

new function:

```
$('#addColumn').click(function(){
                $('#contentTable').css('width', $('#contentTable').width()+150)
                $('#contentTable tr:last').before('<td style="+"width:150px"+">NEW_COLUMN</td>')
            });
```

result:

[image]

Comment: you wrote `append` what do you expect. learn & study jQuery API before posting please.

Comment: @vsync Thank you for the most helpful answer

Comment: no worries mate! that tip is worth **gold** :) on the house!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#addColumn').click(function(){
  $('#contentTable').css('width', $('#contentTable').width()+150);
    $("#contentTable tr").each(function(ind, el){
      if(ind == 0)
        $(el).find('td:eq(-1)').before('<td style="width:150px">Col</td>');
      else
        $(el).find('td:eq(-1)').before('<td style="width:150px"></td>');
  });
});
```

try this one

Comment: it adds column to every rows expect header

Comment: Header of table in th tag ot tr?

Comment: `th` is in table, I change it and everything works! Thank you very much